# Create TopoJson/GeoJson map of US South East

Tags: d3.js, highcharts, powerbi, geojson, topojson

I need to create a TopoJson or GeoJson file of the US South East, like in this image:

[image]

I can either take the map of the whole US and extract the states I need, or take the individual states and merge them. Either way I don’t know how to approach this. Any ideas will be more than welcome.

Comment: Hi @ps0604, Which library do you use (d3 or Highcharts)?

Comment: Highcharts/Highmaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create a chart with some basic map of the USA with states and use `remove` methods for unwanted points.

```
chart: {
    map: 'countries/us/us-all',
    animation: false,
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var points = this.series[0].points;

            points.forEach(function(p) {
                if (!p.value) {
                    p.remove();

                }
            });

            this.mapZoom(0.56, 7251, -5218);
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v69nsryz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#mapZoom

---

You can also search the Highmaps map collection or create a custom map.

**Map collection:** https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-maps

Comment: If you remove the zoom you will see WA state in the north west, I couldn't find a way to remove it, can you tell why?

Comment: Hi @ps0604, Yes, you are right, we need to use reverse iteration to remove WA state: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pu1b7ftd/

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do the same with the US counties map (filtering by state code, regardless if they have data or not) but since the map has 3200+ counties it takes around 3 minutes to show the result. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: You can try to disable `redraw` in the `remove` method to increase performance. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nm4atgpx/, API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#remove